# JPA - Persist @Temporal LocalDate using a converter

Tags: hibernate, oracle11g, java-8, jpa-2.1

Unable to compile code using `@Temporal` for `LocalDate`.

Entity code

```
...
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private LocalDate creationDate;

public LocalDate getCreationDate() {
    return this.creationDate;
}

public void setCreationDate(LocalDate creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
}
...
```

Converter code

```
@Converter(autoApply=true)
public class DateConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate localDate) {
        return (localDate == null) ? null : Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date date) {
        return (date==null) ? null : Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    }

}
```

persistence.xml

```
...
<persistence-unit name="HR">
    <class>test.Employee</class>
    <class>test.DateConverter</class>
</persistence-unit>
...
```

**Environment**

1. JDK 8
2. Eclipse JEE - 2018-09
3. hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar
4. hibernate-validator-6.0.14.Final.jar
5. hibernate-validator-cdi-6.0.14.Final.jar
6. javax.el-3.0.1-b11.jar
7. jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar
8. validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar
9. hibernate-java8-5.1.0.Final.jar
10. hibernate-entitymanager-5.3.7.Final.jar
11. classmate-1.3.4.jar

Eclipse compile error(at `@Temporal` annotation line, in entity code):

> The persistent field or property for a Temporal type must be of type
>   java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar or java.util.GregorianCalendar

Removing `@Temporal` compiles fine. Isn't it required for date and time classes(`java.time`) in Java8?

Please help resolve the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `@Temporal` annotation is not needed for the new `java.time` package of classes. It was needed for `java.util.Date`, because that "Date" was a an attempt at a one-class-fits-all solution, that only made things worse.

You don't need a converter, either.

Comment: It's important to mention that you need to make sure you are using an implementation that supports JPA 2.2. The support for the new date classes in Java 8 was added in this release. If you are on JPA 2.1 or lower, you will still need a converter if you want to use LocalDate, otherwise it will be saved as a BLOB instead of a date/time column. This article, https://thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/, covers it pretty well.

Comment: They've listed Hibernate `5.3` as their JPA provider. There has been embedded support for these classes since `5.2`. It came separately in `5.1`.